# Excel, find the row for {max(sum(Sheet1(A)+Sheet2(A)+Sheet3(A))} formula without having the sum in any table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I want to calculate the maximum value of a summation of data from 3 different sheets in excel, and find in which row is the maximum value referred to.

To define the maximum I'm using this formula:   `{=MAX(Dead!B2:B182+Soil!B2:B182+Fluid!B2:B182)}`

Note: the sum is not created as a column in the excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `MATCH` function on any array. Since you're using an array formula already to find the max value, you can just enclose the whole thing in a `MATCH`, thus:

`{=MATCH(MAX(Dead!B2:B182+Soil!B2:B182+Fluid!B2:B182),Dead!B2:B182+Soil!B2:B182+Fluid!B2:B182,0)}`

The return will indicate where in the array it finds the maximum value. In this case, you'll need to subtract 1 from the result to find the actual row, since your arrays are starting on row 2.

Comment: Dear Werrf, Thanks a lot for the response. This formula does not work, because as I mentioned above I do not have the sum values in a table. So when asking to lookup a value it wont find anything.

Comment: Sorry, looks like I missed a chunk out when I copied the formula from my test sheet - don't know how that happened! Edited with the full thing. It should work even without having the values anywhere but in the formula.

Comment: Yes, It worked perfectly now! Thanks a lot Warff

Comment: Can I give you any positive review or smth? not sure how this site works!

Comment: To be useful is all the reward I need! Though voting Up and clicking the check mark next to the answer to accept it always helps :)